# Iteration over table and list elements and changing value in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have table where every element is a list.
How to change all fields which value is null to "N/A" in all lists.

```
let 
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("127.0.0.1:9099/query" & "?db=OP" & "&q=select * from data where time >= 1577836800000000000 and time < 1577846800000000000")), 
     results = Source[results], 
     results1 = results{0}, 
     series = results1[series], 
     series1 = series{0}, 
     values = series1[values], 
     #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(values, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), 
     #"Filter Table" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", List.Select(each _ = null) )
```

Comment: let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://127.0.0.1:9099/query" & "?db=OP" & "&q=select * from data where time >= 1577836800000000000 and time < 1577846800000000000")),
    results = Source[results],
    results1 = results{0},
    series = results1[series],
    series1 = series{0},
    values = series1[values],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(values, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Filter Table" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", List.Select(each _ = null) )

Comment: Please edit your post rather than putting that query into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use `Table.ReplaceValue` in conjunction with `Replacer.ReplaceValue`.

Small example is below:

```
let
    someTable = Table.FromColumns({
        {"", null, 0},
        {1, null, 2}
    }, type table [a = any, b = any]),
    replaced = Table.ReplaceValue(someTable, null, "N/A", Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"a", "b"})
in
    replaced
```

which takes me from this:

[image: Input table]

to this:

[image: Output table]

You can replace `someTable` with your own table name, and replace `{"a", "b"}` with the names of the columns you need to update.